# ExtJs 4 File upload with RESTEasy 2.3.0.GA , Invalid JSON response

Tags: extjs4, resteasy, jboss6.x

There is a lot of discussion about this topic but no real solution.

Here is my problem if I use

1) @Produce("application/Json") the json response show up with in <pre> tag

2) if I use @Produce("application/html") or @Produce("text/html"),then resteasy breakdown and  error out with JAXB exception :

Uncaught Ext.Error: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String:

## HTTP Status 500 - Could not find JAXBContextFinder for media type: text/html

**type** Status report

**message** Could not find JAXBContextFinder for media type: text/html

**description** The server encountered an internal error (Could not find JAXBContextFinder for media type: text/html) that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

#### JBoss Web/3.0.0-CR2

I am desperate to get some help and there is some solution that is suggested in the forms:
1) Change the content type to text/html 
2) Update the ExtJs source code
3) Parse the < Pre> tag in from the JSON response
don't want to do 2nd and 3rd but in the Ist, I want a valid JSON output. How can I do that?

Here is is my serverice class:

```
 @POST
    @Path("/bulkUpdate")
    @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
    @Produces({"application/json"})
    public ExtjsJson<DataException> uploadFile(MultipartFormDataInput input) {

        Map<String, List<InputPart>> uploadForm = input.getFormDataMap();
        List<InputPart> inputParts = uploadForm.get("uploadedFile");
        List<DataException> list = new ArrayList<DataException>();
        final ExtjsJson<DataException> returnObj = new ExtjsJson<DataException>();
        for (InputPart inputPart : inputParts) {
            try {
                MultivaluedMap<String, String> header = inputPart.getHeaders();
                String fileName  = getFileName(header);
                InputStream inputStream = inputPart.getBody(InputStream.class, null);
                byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

                //handle the excel file upload and return the error if the file does not have valid data some like...
                DataException error = new DataException("supervisor", "columnName", 1, "SheetName", "this is not a valid supervisor");   
                list.add(error);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        returnObj.setSuccess(true);
        returnObj.setResults(list);
        return returnObj;
    }
```

Here is my response Object DataException.java

```
@Data
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DataException {

    //private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /** excel sheet name */
    private String sheetName;

    /** row number of the excel sheet */
    private int rowNumber;

    /** field name/cell header **/
    private String fieldName;

    /** cell value */
    private String fieldValue;

    private String description;
}
```

Here is the error (JSON response with  tag)

Uncaught Ext.Error: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{"total":1,"success":true,"results":[{"description":"this is not a valid supervisor","fieldName":"supervisor","fieldValue":"testPM","rowNumber":1,"sheetName":"sheet1"}]}</pre>

Comment: come on guys, give me some direction here!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my solution was:

1. use `@Produces("text/html")`
2. your method need to send back a String to the frontend:

   `public String uploadFile (...)`
3. easiest way is to implement a `toString()` method in the ExtjsJson class which returns it in String format.